# C++ no suitable constructor exists to convert from "TCHAR [260]" to "std::basic_string<char, std:char_traits<char>"

Tags: c++

I got this problem and i don't know how to fix it. It was working fine since some days.
If someone know how to fix it i really need him...

```cpp
inline uint64_t GetModuleBaseAddr()
    {
        HMODULE h_modules[1024];
        DWORD pcb_needed;

        handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

        if (K32EnumProcessModules(handle, h_modules, sizeof(h_modules), &pcb_needed))
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (pcb_needed / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
            {
                TCHAR module_name[MAX_PATH];
                if (GetModuleFileNameEx(handle, h_modules[i], module_name, sizeof(module_name) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
                {
                    std::string str_module_name = module_name; // <-- HERE THE ERROR
                    if (str_module_name.find(name) != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        base = (uint64_t)h_modules[i];
                        return base;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "It was working fine since some days" - then why don't you check out the version of your code you had "a few days ago" from your source control software (like `git`) and then pick up from there?

Comment: check `sizeof(TCHAR)` and `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: Your project is set to use the Unicode character set so `TCHAR` is a wide type. You could use `std::wstring`, change the project to multi-byte, or use `char module_name[MAX_PATH];` and `GetModuleFileNameExA`.

Comment: `(uint64_t)h_modules[i];` frightens me. A lot can go wrong with that simple statement. Are you absolutely certain that a `HMODULE` can be represented as a 64 bit unsigned int?

Comment: @user4581301 yes, it can, at least for now.  A `HMODULE` is a `void*`, which will fit into a 64bit integer (until 128bit systems come around). Though, it would be better to use `reinterpret_cast` instead of a C-style cast, and use `uintptr_t` instead of `uint64_t`.

Comment: If you are not using version control software (which you should) then you should at least be taking snapshots as zip archives or copied folders.  Everyone has made changes that broke something, and needed to compare old and new versions of code at some point.   Also, you need backups, and NOT all on the same hard drive or USB key.  Losing days, weeks, or months of work is no fun.